# How to send ArrayList using volley in android?

Tags: android, hashmap, android-volley

How to send ArrayList using volley in android,
How to use ArrayList in HashMap?
like  `Map<String, ArrayList<String> params ;`

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got a easiest and perfect solution:

use this dependency:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

and use this line

```
String data = new Gson().toJson(myArrayList);
```

Now you can pass this string into volley as string parameters like bellow example.

Example:

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                String data = new Gson().toJson(myArrayList);
                params.put("keyName", data);
                return params;
            }
```

Working for me.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know How to use ArrayList in HashMap?
BUT!!!
for sending ArrayList using volley you can do this

```
 private void sendData(ArrayList list) throws JSONException {

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, YOUR_URL, setJsonObject(list)/*This is the function you need*/, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {


        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LogInActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjReq);
}


//create json object that contain ArrayList contents  
private JSONObject setJsonObject(َArrayList list) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject jsonobject_one = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

    for(int i =0 ; i<list.size ; i++) {

    JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
    jsonobject .put("param"+i, list.get(i) );
    jsonArray.put(jsonobject);

    }

    jsonobject_one.put("params_array",jsonArray);
    return jsonobject_one;

}
```